# How to block login to carbon by user in wso2 api manager 3.2.0?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I defined a user x and I would like to user x could not to login into `/carbon`, I just give `/publisher` permission but user x can also login into `/carbon`.

Comment: I believe you have assigned `Internal/publisher` role to the user. Is that the case? or did you assign any custom role to the user?

Comment: Yes I assigened Internal/publisher role to user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the login permission from `Internal/publisher` prevents users from login to Management Console. In order to remove the permission:

- Login to Management Console as Admin user
- Edit `Permisssions` of `Internal/publisher`

[image]

- Untick the `Login` permission under `Admin Permissions` and `Update`.